# Query for the bugs that has been addressed by name in discussion session

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to query for the bugs that has been addressed by name in discussion session?

Discussion will have @Name, but the bug isn't assigned to me.

I tried the "History and Contains with" which didn't work.

Comment: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19779064-query-discussion-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not able to directly query the comment in discussion field of a work item.

The history of a work item tells you who opened the item, what changed, and why. When you perform a search on the contents of the History field, it returns only **work items that have changes recorded** in that field.

As a workaround you could use history filed to get what you need, filter for items you have been associated with `History _ Contains Words _ YourName`, detail query should be something as below:

[image]

More details about the history query, see [History and auditing](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/history-and-auditing)

Since the workaround not to be quite accurate. It will return not only the discussion but also any other filed including your name and not assigned to you.  Another way is using Rest API to [get work item discussion history](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/history#a-page-at-a-time), and then filter the history with *@yourname*. Detail steps how to do this, please refer this sample: [RETRIEVE WORK ITEM DISCUSSION HISTORY USING  REST API](https://blog.siliconvalve.com/2014/05/16/retrieve-work-item-discussion-history-using-visual-studio-onlines-rest-api/)